# Puppet breaks with multiple node inheritances

Tags: puppet

Puppet on the tst-01 works fine when using:

```
node "tst-01" inherits basenode {
```

But it breaks when I try to organize servers into groups with this configuration:

```
node "tst-01" inherits redhat6server {
```

The error with "inherits redhat6server" is:

```
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
[root@tst-01 ~]# puppet agent --test
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Failed to parse template ldap/access.conf: Could not find value for 'netgroup' at 124:/etc/puppet/modules/ldap/templates/access.conf at /etc/puppet/modules/ldap/manifests/init.pp:82 on node tst-01.tst.it.test.com
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
err: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

This is the access.conf file, that works fine if inherits is set to "inherits basenode".

```
[root@puppet]# grep -v "#" /etc/puppet/modules/ldap/templates/access.conf 
+ : root : LOCAL
+ : @<%= netgroup %> : ALL
- : ALL : ALL
[root@puppet]#
```

This is the configuration in /etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp.

```
# Basenode configuration
node "basenode" {
        include resolv_conf
        include sshd
        include ntpd
        include motd
}

# Groups
node "redhat6server" inherits basenode {
        include ldap_auth
}

# Testservers
node "tst-01" inherits redhat6server {
        $netgroup = tst-01
}
```

I am planning to bring more organisation (read: avoid configuration repetition) in the nodes.pp by grouping machines, e.g. RH5 and RH6 machines instead of adding multiple lines of includes for all RH5 and RH6 servers.

Comment: are you just missing a double quote in "tst-01" when assigning the value to $netgroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your running into a variable scoping problem.  The official [documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_scope.html) discusses this issue.

In short, `redhat6server` doesn't have access to the netgroup variable.

The method I employ to work around this is to use [hiera](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/hiera/1/puppet.html).  With this, the ldap_auth module can be defined this way, and it will pull the value from a hiera configuration file (typically a yaml file in /etc/puppet/hiera).

You would defined ldap_auth like this:

ldap_auth/manifests/init.pp:

```
class ldap_auth($netgroup=hiera('netgroup')) {
...
}
```

Or if your on puppet 3.x, you can use automatic parameter lookup:

```
class ldap_auth($netgroup) {
...
}
```

And have a yaml file with:

```
ldap_auth::netgroup = 'netgroup'
```